# Use Cron job to visit website and write output to file

Tags: cron

I like to know is there any way to use cron job to visit my site every 30 seconds then write or append to a log file so that I can later see any errors. I have tried the follow and it does not work every 30 seconds and there is no file It would also be nice if there was a way to only write output to file if there was a 500 error

```
* * * * * wget -O - http://yoursite.com/505check.html >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2>&1` means that you have redirected your stderror pipe to stdout pipe.

Now, your output pipe is redirected to a special location `/dev/null` which is always an empty file.

So you will never see output.

On top of that, `* * * * *` means every minmute in cron, not every 30 seconds.

#### Solution

```sh
//overwrites a file every minute
* * * * * wget -O - http://yoursite.com/505check.html > ${some_file_path} 2>&1

//appends to a file every minute
* * * * * wget -O - http://yoursite.com/505check.html >> ${some_file_path} 2>&1
```